# Dúvida Model Service DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou com um dúvida sobre um projeto que segue o modelo de arquitetura DDD.

Em um model service eu preciso de uma informação que é resultado de um método de um outro service, qual a maneira correta de eu obter essa informação, eu crio uma propriedade desse service e coloco ela no construtor para fazer a injeção de dependência ou devo obter essa informação na camada anterior, a mesma que eu chamo esse primeiro service e passo esse valor como parâmetro?

A minha dúvida se da pq eu criei a propriedade de segundo service e fiz a injeção de dependência mas depois deu erro pq diz que existe referências de injeção de dependência cíclica e preciso remover a propriedade desse segundo service e a injeção de dependência.

Comment: Tem código? poderia colocar na pergunta pra gente poder te ajudar melhor?

Answer (score 0):

É difícil responder sem saber o contexto, mas vou tentar.

Se os dois services dependem entre si, aconselho a criar um terceiro service que injeta os dois primeiros e realiza a ponte entre eles.

Exemplo:

Serviço_Alfa -> Método_Um(Serviço_Beta)

Serviço_Beta -> Método_Dois(Serviço_Alfa)

Serviço_Delta -> Recebe Alfa e Beta por DI.

Serviço_Delta -> Método_Três() -> Executa a operação em Alfa passando Beta como parâmetro.

Serviço_Delta -> Método_Quatro() -> Executa a operação em Beta, passando Alfa como parâmetro.